# Merge two lists using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have three Models something like this:

```
public class Section
{
  public string Id {get; set;}

  public SubSection[] SubSections {get; set;}

  public Item[] Items {get; set;}
}

public class SubSection
{
  public string Id {get; set;}

  public string sectionId {get; set;}

  public Item[] Items {get; set;}
}

public class Item
{
  public string Id {get; set;}

  public string sectionId {get; set;}
}
```

Now when I get the result back I get back list of Sections and Items and would like to merge these two lists to put it into the above Models.

Everything is connected with Section Id; determining where the item goes in SubSection or directly under section and the subsections go under section array.

Is there a good way to do this using Linq?

Example:

```
Item { id = "123", sectionId = "456"}
Item {id = "234", sectionId = "786"}

SubSection {id = "211", sectionId = "786", Items = null}
SubSection {id = "210", sectionId = 456", Items[] = new Item() {"123"}}

Section {id = 786, subsections[] = null, items[] =  new Item() {"234" }}
Section {id = 456, subsection[] = new SubSection { id = 210}, items = null}
```

Comment: "Now when I get the result back"... How do you get it? Is it through a Web API? ORM call? In-memory collection?

Comment: Yes, Its from the Web API and it's returned as IList<Item> itemList and IList<Section> section List --> Internally even SubSection is treated as Section...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ is good at reading and transforming, but not at modifying items where they stand. It's doable (a right way and a "wrong" way), but unless you specifically need that, I'll focus on what you're asking here.

```
List<SectionWithoutCollections> sections;
List<SubSectionWithoutCollections> subSections;
List<Item> items;

var subSectionsWithItems = subSections
    .GroupJoin(items, a => a.Id, b => b.SectionId, (a,b) => new SubSection
               {
                   Id = a.Id,
                   SectionId = a.SectionId,
                   Items = b.ToArray()
               });

var sectionsWithItems = sections
    .GroupJoin(subSectionsWithItems, a => a.Id, b => b.SectionId, (a,b) => new { Section = a, SubSections = b })
    .GroupJoin(items, a => a.Section.Id, b => b.SectionId, (a,b) => new Section
               {
                   Id = a.Section.Id,
                   Items = b.ToArray(),
                   SubSections = a.SubSections.ToArray()
               });
```

I did this in two steps, but you could do it in one, if readability didn't matter (which is always does).

It's pretty straight-forward once you know the methods, but basically I put all the subsections and items together, then I put all the sections and subsections together, then I put all the sections-and-subsections and items together.

Just note that any orphaned items or subsections (i.e. those for which no section or subsection with `SectionId` exist) will be thrown out. But that's bad relational anyway, so that's acceptable, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sections = new List<Section>();
        var subSections = new List<SubSection>();
        var items = new List<Item>();

        var itemSections = from s in sections
                           let i = items.Where(j => j.sectionId == s.Id).DefaultIfEmpty().ToArray()
                           let ss = subSections.Where(j => j.sectionId == s.Id).DefaultIfEmpty().ToArray()

                           select new Section
                           {
                               Id = s.Id,
                               SubSections = ss,
                               Items = i
                           };
```

This should work, haven't tested. Not sure what you mean by Merge tho